# MYSQL slow after long run, only gets better on resetting server

Tags: mysql

I have a large-ish (1 million entries) mysql table.  Im running on AWS ec2 with nginx/node.  Queries are fast for a while but then slow down after a month or so of up time (queries that generally take 150ms where taking 4+ seconds). I tried flushing/reindexing.  I tried restarting just the mysql server and still slow queries.
I looked at memory on system and it seemed fine.
The only thing that helped was rebooting the instance and it worked quick again.  Its working fine now, but obviously this isnt right.
Any ideas for next time,
Thanks all.

Comment: I think this question is better for [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I will try that; but it seems like it might be a linux configuration issue? not an issue directly with db